# Lumen throwing error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Laravel\Lumen\Bootstrap\LoadEnvironmentVariables' not found in /var/www/bootstrap/app.php:5

Tags: laravel, lumen

I am working on a Laravel Lumen project. I am trying to spin up the existing project locally. First I installed the composer by running, "composer install". When I run the migration command, "php artisan migrate", I am getting the following error.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Laravel\Lumen\Bootstrap\LoadEnvironmentVariables' not found in /var/www/bootstrap/app.php:5
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/artisan(18): require()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/bootstrap/app.php on line 5
```

I tried deleting the vendor folder and running composer install again. It did not work. The class does not seem to exist either. But the composer was installed successfully. I am using Lumen version 7.0. What is wrong with it and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you actually require the lumen package i.e. make sure your composer.json contains:

```
"require": {
   "php": "^7.2.5",
   "laravel/lumen-framework": "^7.0"
},
```

Afterwards run composer install again. If it worked then a folder /vendor/laravel/lumen-framework should be present

- See official composer.json template for Lumen 7.0: https://github.com/laravel/lumen/blob/7.x/composer.json